# Problema con consulta en Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
PROCEDURE PP_TRAER_DESC_CLI IS
V_BLOQUEADO  FIN_CLIENTE.CLI_BLOQ_LIM_CR%TYPE;
V_ESTADO     FIN_CLIENTE.CLI_EST_CLI%TYPE;
V_MAX_DIAS_ATRASO NUMBER;
V_CLI_NOM VARCHAR2(80);
V_CLI_DIR VARCHAR2(80);
--*
BEGIN   
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT CLI_CODIGO, CLI_NOM, NVL(CLI_DIR,'**'), SUBSTR(CLI_TEL,1,15), 
CLI_RUC, 
     CLI_PERS_REPRESENTANTE, CLI_DOC_IDENT_REPRESENTANTE,
     CLI_LOCALIDAD, CLI_PORC_EXEN_IVA
INTO   :BDOC_ENCA.DOC_CLI,
         V_CLI_NOM,
     V_CLI_DIR,
     :BDOC_ENCA.DOC_CLI_TEL,
     :BDOC_ENCA.DOC_CLI_RUC,
       :BDOC_ENCA.CLI_PERS_REPRESENTANTE,
       :BDOC_ENCA.CLI_DOC_IDENT_REPRESENTANTE,
     :PARAMETER.P_CLI_LOCALIDAD,
     :BDOC_ENCA.W_CLI_PORC_EXEN_IVA
 FROM   FIN_CLIENTE
 WHERE  CLI_CODIGO = :BDOC_ENCA.S_CLI;
 ) WHERE ROWNUM 1;
 :PARAMETER.P_CLI_DIR := NVL(V_CLI_DIR,'**');

 IF NVL(:BDOC_ENCA.DOC_CLI,0) <> NVL(:BDOC_ENCA.W_ANT_DOC_CLI,0) THEN
 :BDOC_ENCA.CLI_NOM := V_CLI_NOM;
 :BDOC_ENCA.CLI_DIR := V_CLI_DIR;
 END IF;

 --*
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
 PL_EXHIBIR_ERROR('Cliente inexistente.');
 WHEN FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE THEN
 RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
 PL_EXHIBIR_ERROR_PLSQL;
 END;
```

El error que lanza es:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te das cuenta de que has puesto ese INTO dentro de una subconsulta? Qué haría entonces la select de fuera? Traer las variables? No tendría sentido. Revisa la query, un saludo.